# Looping Divs (jQuery Carousel)

Tags: jquery, css, single-page-application

I've build a single page app and everything is working except for one section. Here it is:

http://efeldberg.biz/assets/projects/HTML5_Banners/ArtInstitute/ColorPicker.html

I've tried multiple attempts to get the swatches section to loop like a carousel so the user can click either arrow indefinitely and the swatches will continue to scroll in the same direction.

I've tried anythingSlider, misc scripts, my own JS and CSS3 but can't get this. Suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post some code? Questions on SO should be helpful also for other visitors in the future.

Comment: I can't seem to post my code. Links from JS fiddle don't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've *almost* got it!

When the 2nd scene loads it looks like you animate the left margin of `#swatchContent` -503 pixels. Remove this, or animate `left` instead. It looks like this has been screwing with your math.

Then all you need to do is fix your terminal numbers. It looks like you go one block's width too far to the right before it swings back around, so reduce that and you should be good.

Here I've removed the left margin with jQuery. Using the arrows now seems to work as intended (until you hit the end, gotta update the reset position to 0px):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get this to work probably because I didn't understand this completely.

Answer (score 0):

You did not shared your code so I'll share mine.
http://jsbin.com/paqim/4/edit and you've got yourself a nice infinite slider.

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="swatches">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
    <button id="prev">&#9664;</button>
    <button id="next">&#9654;</button>
</div>
```

jQ:

```
var $s = $("#swatches"),
    $b = $('#prev, #next'),
    $d = function(fl){return $('>div',$s)[fl]();},
    px = 260; // Animation px

$s.prepend( $d('last') ).scrollLeft( px ); // Prepend last + reset pos to '1'.

$b.click(function() {
  if( !$s.is(':animated')){
    if(this.id=="next") $s.animate({scrollLeft:px*2}, 400, function() {
        $s.scrollLeft(px).append($d('first'));
    });
    else $s.prepend($d('last')).scrollLeft(px*2).animate({scrollLeft:px}, 400);
  }
});
```